# tableView not loading data from parse

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a function called loadData

```
func loadData(){
    feedData.removeAllObjects()

    var findFeedData:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "userQuotes")

    findFeedData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?)->Void in

        if error == nil{
            if let objs = objects{
            for object in objs{
                let quote:PFObject = object as! PFObject
                self.feedData.addObject(quote)
            }

            let array:NSArray = self.feedData.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects
            self.feedData = NSMutableArray(array: array)

            self.tableView.reloadData() 
            }
        }

    }
}
```

and then in the cellForRowAtIndexPath I actually get the data and display it. I self.loadData() in the viewDidLoad function.

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:QuoteTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! QuoteTableViewCell

    let quote:PFObject = self.feedData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject

    cell.contentTextView.text = quote.objectForKey("content") as! String

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
}
```

I am getting no compiler errors and everything seems to be working. The content gets pushed to parse but it doesn't load with these functions. All that runs is an empty table view cells When it should be displaying content from Parse. I feel I am missing something simple logically here... I am a beginner so pardon any silly mistakes. I am following a tutorial but that is a bit outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Verify these methods:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1 //or more if you want
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.feedData.count
}
```

Comment: Please use the proper markup in your comment. Your comments consists of plenty of code, please edit it so it can easily be identified as such.

Comment: I was returning 0 in the numberOfSectionsInTableView, so It returns 1 now. I had returned the numberOfRowsInSection as self.feedData.count already.

Comment: `  let cell:QuoteTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! QuoteTableViewCell
`  in this line I get a SIGABRT error

Comment: If you are using storyboard make sure your tableviewcell use your class QuoteTableViewCell

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a mutable array, you will need to initialize it before adding in objects.

Comment: I have initialized it in the previous line

Comment: Can you check if you are getting data into the array self.feedData before the line `let array:NSArray = self.feedData.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects`.

Comment: I println'd the array into the console and it is printing all my data

Comment: Check if the table view delegate and datasource are connected and if it still doesn't work try reloading the table on main thread by doing something like this. `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}`

Comment: For the SIGABRT you need to register your cell first and make sure if you have given the identifier to the cell.

Comment: Thank you so much for the SIGABRT error check... that was really dumb of me not to check. I renamed the textview where I displayed the content and reattached it. The other identifier wasn't deleted and I got the error. thanks for the help

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please mark this answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing UI on an asynchronous thread.

The call to parse is async. When this call completes you are reloading your table view.

You should instead dequeu your UI change to the main thread

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
  self.tableView.reloadData() 
}
```